# Unable to read environment variables outside a function in go with os.Getenv("KEY")

Tags: go

I am a newbie to go, while using sling to make api calls to an external service
when I do
`var api = sling.New().Base(os.Getenv("BASE_URL"))`
the value comes as ""

but when I do the same in a function to debug

```
var api = sling.New().Base(os.Getenv("BASE_URL")) // raw url is blank
var api2=os.Getenv("BASE_URL")
type Params struct{
//params defined
}

func GetInfo(){

//params set

log.debug("base url:",os.Getenv("BASE_URL")) // prints "www.example.com/" as set in .env file
log.debug("base url from outside the function :",api2) //also empty
    if _, err := api.New().Get("trailingURL/rest").QueryStruct(params).ReceiveSuccess(response); err != nil || !response.Successful() {
        
        return false
    } // fails as base url is not set

}
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: The value of the ENV variable does not vary whether you are inside or outside of a function. Are you sure `os.Getenv("BASE_URL")` comes blank in the first line or is it `api` that comes blank? If you print `os.Getenv("BASE_URL")` before you call `sling.New().Base()` you should see the value. I suspect the call to `sling.New().Base()` is the problem.

Comment: @HectorCorrea this fails when I directly initialise the value to a variable too. are the global variables initialised at compile time and the env variables loaded after it? any idea in the order of initialisation

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference where `os.Getenv` is called. In this basic example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var v = os.Getenv("FOO")

func GetInfo() {
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("FOO"))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(v)
    GetInfo()
}
```

If you run it with `FOO=42 <program>`, then it will print 42 twice.

---

In your code I'd say the difference is that the global initialization calls `sling.New().Base` while the function doesn't. If I was debugging this, that's where I'd be looking for a difference.

Start by adding an `api2` global alongside `api`:

```
var api = sling.New().Base(os.Getenv("BASE_URL"))
var api2 = os.Getenv("BASE_URL")
```

And then printing/logging the value of both, and see what you get.

Comment: value of api2 is also empty

Comment: @Lucas: keep bisecting between the global scope (which happens at program init) and where `GetInfo` is called. Maybe this value is set by the program itself somewhere after initialization?

Comment: the GetInfo method is part of an api, which in-turn calls another api, so I would say the call comes after the server is up and running

Comment: I figured it out, after server starts, we call a common method which loads the .env file based on environment , but these global variables would be initialised by then, hence they hold blank values, my bad..

Comment: @Lucas: no worries, we've all been there. Finding a point where "it works", another point where "it doesn't work" and then bisecting between them is a battle-tested debugging strategy born out of many folks tearing out their hairs :-) Glad you fixed your issue